# Are these var declarations a matter of style or functionality?

Tags: javascript

ES5, the most widely used implementation of JavaScript, currently does not have block scope so is it best practice to put your idiomatic variable declarations in the for statement or outside of it?

**Option-1**

```
for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

**Option-2**

```
var i; 
var l = arr.length;
for(i = 0; i < l; i++ ){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

Is this simply a style preference or is there a best practice ?

Comment: *"JavaScript currently does not have block scope..."* Yes it does, as of about two years ago (ES2015, aka "ES6").

Comment: In ES2015 you can use `let`  statement that declares a block scope local variable

Comment: option1 is more readable, widely used and therefore should be preferred while option2 may seems like alien code traditionally just to appease lint :P

Comment: Where can I get a feel for which browsers have **actually started implementing ES6**

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=let

Comment: Which style do you think is more human-friendly? That's the style you should use.

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ES6+browser+support&*

Comment: @brannonteer: Started to? All of them. And Chrome, Firefox, and Edge have decent ES2015 support today; details here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 1):

With `var`, this is a style question.

But as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), JavaScript got block scope for variables if you use `let` and `const`. So

```
for (let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

vs.

```
let i; 
let l = arr.length;
for(i = 0; i < l; i++ ){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

is **not** purely a style question. There are two things to consider:

1. With the first, of course, `i` and `l` are scoped to the `for` loop (though possibly not quite how you expect), whereas with the second they're in the scope containing the `for` loop.
2. With the first, there is a **new** `i` and `l` for every loop iteration (really), which can have an effect on performance; with the second, there's only one `i` and `l` shared by all loop iterations (and the containing scope).

#2 makes a big difference to any functions you create in the loop, as you can see with this example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("let inside the loop, i = " + i);
  }, 0);
}

let j;
for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("let outside the loop, j = " + j);
  }, 0);
}
```

On an ES2015-compliant browser, that outputs:

```
let inside the loop, i = 0
let inside the loop, i = 1
let inside the loop, i = 2
let outside the loop, j = 3
let outside the loop, j = 3
let outside the loop, j = 3
```

Notice how the values of `i` go `0` to `2`, but the value of `j` is always `3` (like it would be with `var`). That's because there's a **different** `i` variable for each loop iteration, but there's only one `j` variable shared by all loop iterations.

**Note:** IE9-IE11 have `let`, but are **not** ES2015-compliant. If you run the above in them, you'll see `3` for `i` as well as `j`.